# Select option in drop down menu HTML

Tags: html, html-select, forms

I want to beable to select an option in a select by the value that has been gotten from the session is this possible? So eg in my list:

- Book
- Conference
- Journal

And for example book was in the session so it selects the book in the drop down menu. 

Thanks in Advance

Dean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i give following example with the help of ruby language. which select the 'Book' when session[:some] contains string 'Book'

```
<select>
 <option value="Book" <%= 'selected' if session[:some]=="Book" %>>Book</option>
 <option value="Conference"  <%= 'selected' if session[:some]=="Conference" %>>Conference</option>
 <option value="Journal"  <%= 'selected' if session[:some]=="Journal" %>>Journal</option>
<select>
```

In pure HTML

```
<select name="">
 <option value="Book" 'selected'>Book</option>
 <option value="Conference" >Conference</option>
 <option value="Journal" >Journal</option>
<select>
```

Comment: You should use `selected="selected"` or `selected="true"` as valid HTML.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML attribute `selected` can be set for the option(s) you want selected.

As far as the session, you didn't describe how you are capturing that information - JavaScript, PHP, etc. If you specify this, you may get some sample code.

Comment: I wasn't to bothered about sample code just needed to know how to select an option from existing data. Thanks for the answer.